# React state does not toggle on click

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sorting, react-hooks, toggle

I have a state that contains the order of the sorting. When I press a button, I want to toggle the sorting order, from -1 to 1 and back.

```
const [order, setOrder] = React.useState(1);
function handleSort(elementIndex) {
    let firstSort = -1;
    let secondSort = 1;
    setContent((prev) => {
        prev.sort((line1, line2) => {
            return line1.props.children[elementIndex].props.children >
                line2.props.children[elementIndex].props.children
                ? firstSort * order
                : secondSort * order;
        });
        console.log(prev);
        return [...prev];
    });
    setOrder((prev) => prev * -1);
}

<button
    onClick={() => {
        handleSort(
            temporaryHeadersArrayCopy.findIndex(
                (elem) => elem === element
            )
        );
    }}
>
```

This is just a fraction of the code, but the main problem is that the order never modifies. I tried console logging, but from what I have read, it does not change immediately because it is a callback and it works async.

Thank you!

Comment: Update: Modified the approach to not save the direction in a state, rather in a variable, that is modified in the handleSort function. This work properly, so I can consider the problem resolved.

Comment: You never run `setOrder`

Comment: I use it when I press the button and call the handleSort function.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what you want to do with this code. But you have an array you want to sort, based on an index. Am I right?

I would use useMemo, with the actual array and the index as dependencies. This should ensure that your sorted array updates whenever one of the dependencies change.

Comment: Yes, it is a table dynamically formed. I didn't post the full code, but to simplify the matter, the handleSort function gets the column by which the table should be sorted. I managed to fix this by not saving the order in a state, rather use a variable sortDirection that changes each time I press the button. I am not entirely sure if I miss some good practices by doing that, because I am not using a state. Thank you for the response!